# Convert numpy array to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array of size `31x36` and i want to transform into pandas dataframe in order to process it. I am trying to convert it using the following code:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=matrix,
          index=np.array(range(1, 31)),
          columns=np.array(range(1, 36)))
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (36, 31), indices imply (35, 30)

How can I solve the issue and transform it properly?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(matrix)` would work, no? To use custom index, this is another option: `pd.DataFrame(arr).rename(index=lambda x: x + 1, columns=lambda x: x + 1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As to why what you tried failed, the ranges are off by 1

```
pd.DataFrame(data=matrix,
          index=np.array(range(1, 32)),
          columns=np.array(range(1, 37)))
```

As the last value isn't included in the range

Actually looking at what you're doing you could've just done:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=matrix,
          index=np.arange(1, 32)),
          columns=np.arange(1, 37)))
```

Or in pure `pandas`:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=matrix,
          index=pd.RangeIndex(range(1, 32)),
          columns=pd.RangeIndex(range(1, 37)))
```

Also if you don't specify the index and column params, an auto-generated index and columns is made, which will start from `0`. Unclear why you need them to start from `1`

You could also have not passed the index and column params and just modified them after construction:

```
In[9]:
df = pd.DataFrame(adaption)
df.columns = df.columns+1
df.index = df.index + 1
df

Out[9]: 
          1         2         3         4         5         6
1 -2.219072 -1.637188  0.497752 -1.486244  1.702908  0.331697
2 -0.586996  0.040052  1.021568  0.783492 -1.263685 -0.192921
3 -0.605922  0.856685 -0.592779 -0.584826  1.196066  0.724332
4 -0.226160 -0.734373 -0.849138  0.776883 -0.160852  0.403073
5 -0.081573 -1.805827 -0.755215 -0.324553 -0.150827 -0.102148
```

Answer (score 5):

You meet an error because the `end` argument in `range(start, end)` is *non-inclusive*. You have a couple of options to account for this:

#### Don't pass index and columns

Just use `df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)`. The `pd.DataFrame` constructor adds integer indices implicitly.

#### Pass in the shape of the array

`matrix.shape` gives a tuple of row and column count, so you need not specify them manually. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=range(matrix.shape[0]),
                          columns=range(matrix.shape[1]))
```

If you need to start at `1`, remember to add 1:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=range(1, matrix.shape[0] + 1),
                          columns=range(1, matrix.shape[1] + 1))
```

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? Using `matrix` properties directly is the natural solution here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer,`range(1, X)` describes the set of numbers from `1` up to `X-1` inclusive. You need to use `range(1, 32)` and `range(1, 37)` to do what you describe.