# How to convert 3-D Numpy array to Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**The problem**: 
I have a 3-D Numpy Array:

`X`

`X.shape: (1797, 2, 500)`

```
z=X[..., -1]
print(len(z))
print(z.shape)
count = 0
for bot in z:
    print(bot)
    count+=1
    if count == 3: break
```

Above code yields following output:

```
1797
(1797, 2)
[23.293915 36.37388 ]
[21.594519 32.874397]
[27.29872  26.798382]
```

So, there are 1797 data points - each with a X and a Y coordinate
and, there are 500 iterations of these 1797 points.

I want a DataFrame such that:

```
Index Column       |  X-coordinate  |  Y-coordinate
0                  |  X[0][0][0]    |  X[0][1][0]
0                  |  X[1][0][0]    |  X[1][1][0]
0                  |  X[2][0][0]    |  X[2][1][0]
('0') 1797 times
1                  |  X[0][0][1]    |  X[0][1][1]
1                  |  X[1][0][1]    |  X[1][1][1]
1                  |  X[2][0][1]    |  X[2][1][1]
('1' 1797 times)
.
.
.
and so on
till 500
```

I tried techniques mentioned here, but numpy/pandas is really escaping me:

1. [How To Convert a 3D Array To a Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52195426/how-to-convert-a-3d-array-to-a-dataframe)
2. [How to transform a 3d arrays into a dataframe in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525028/how-to-transform-a-3d-arrays-into-a-dataframe-in-python)
3. [Convert numpy array to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50624046/convert-numpy-array-to-pandas-dataframe)
4. [easy multidimensional numpy ndarray to pandas dataframe method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853594/easy-multidimensional-numpy-ndarray-to-pandas-dataframe-method)
5. [numpy rollaxis - how exactly does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583792/numpy-rollaxis-how-exactly-does-it-work)

Please help me out.
Hope I am adhering to the question-asking discipline.

Comment: Question-asking discipline says: show what you tried and explain why it did not work. Here is the authoritative link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @MadPhysicist, my apologies. Please let me update the question.

Comment: Once again, sincere apologies to the forum and @MadPhysicist, while I was working on preparing pointers you asked for, I got notifications with some responses to the question which have solved my problem. This was my first ever question and will really take care from next time onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution with sample data:

```
a,b,c = X.shape
# in your case
# a,b,c = 1797, 500

pd.DataFrame(X.transpose(1,2,0).reshape(2,-1).T,
             index=np.repeat(np.arange(c),a),
             columns=['X_coord','Y_coord'] 
            )
```

Output:

```
   X_coord  Y_coord
0        0        3
0        6        9
0       12       15
0       18       21
1        1        4
1        7       10
1       13       16
1       19       22
2        2        5
2        8       11
2       14       17
2       20       23
```

Comment: Hello @Quang, thank you so much for the prompt answer. It has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
index = np.concatenate([np.repeat([i], 1797) for i in range(500)])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
df['X-coordinate'] = X[:, 0, :].T.reshape((-1))
df['Y-coordinate'] = X[:, 1, :].T.reshape((-1))
```

Comment: Hi @Bruno, thank you so much for the prompt response. I tried with your approach too, and it solved the problem too.